# Calculate price with mysql query

Tags: mysql, cart

gurus! I am stuck. Catalog items have prices dependent to its quantity. Here example of tables:

```
items: just item definitions
-------------------------
item_id | item_title
-------------------------
1       | "sample item"
2       | "another item"

items_prices: prices dependent to item quantity. 
              Less price taken for more quantity of item
----------------------------
item_id | quantity  | price
----------------------------
1       | 1         | 100
1       | 5         | 80
1       | 10        | 60
2       | 1         | 120
2       | 3         | 100

cart
-------------------
item_id | quantity  
-------------------
1       | 20
2       | 2
```

Is it possible to get current cart cost with single query?

Comment: It would be easier if `items_prices` had `min_quantity` and `max_quantity`.

Comment: oh! min_quantity = quantity in my example.

Comment: Yes, I got that. Adding a `max_quantity` field will make the query you desire really [relatively] easy, though it may duplicate data. (I say "may", because it'll also give you the option to disallow certain values of quantity, which may be useful.)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, i see, thank you! But this make me die tonight. Every new items_prices record i have to recalculate min | max quantities for certain items. It's more complicated for now. Maybe. Probably,.. Let me think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(x.totalcost)
from (
    select c.item_id, c.quantity * ip.price as totalcost
    from cart c
    join items_prices ip
      on c.item_id = ip.item_id
    left join items_prices ip2
      on ip2.quantity > ip.quantity
      and c.quantity >= ip2.quantity
    where c.quantity >= ip.quantity
      and ip2.quantity is null
) x
```

The join back onto items_price again lets us filter out any cases where there is a greater quantity which still meets our criteria.  This should be getting close to what we're after

Comment: How can these 2: `.... ip2.quantity >= ip.quantity and ip2.quantity is null` both be true??

Comment: left join's behaving rationally, but not how I expected.  I __think__ sliding the conditional up to the join cleans that up.

Comment: One final edit; need to get rid of the limit term, and don't need the order by term any longer.  I have verified this and get 1440, which looks to be correct.

Comment: Single price row in `item_prices` make your query returns empty result. can u help me last time please? :)